# What is the allowed syntax for a Github release tag_name?

Tags: github, tagname, http-status-code-422, github-release

The apps I'm trying to place under version control store their version number as a timestamp...

`2019-12-28T05:13:47Z` .

When I try to add this timestamp as a [Github release `tag_name` using the API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#create-a-release)...

```
{
  "tag_name": "2019-12-28T05:13:47Z",
  "target_commitish": "master",
  "name": "2019-12-28T05:13:47Z",
  "body": "LATEST RELEASE",
  "draft": false,
  "prerelease": false
}
```

I get a status 422 error...

```
{
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "resource": "Release",
      "code": "custom",
      "field": "tag_name",
      "message": "tag_name is not a valid tag"
    },
    {
      "resource": "Release",
      "code": "custom",
      "field": "tag_name",
      "message": "tag_name is not well-formed"
    },
    {
      "resource": "Release",
      "code": "custom",
      "message": "Published releases must have a valid tag"
    }
  ],
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#create-a-release"
}
```

If I change the tag to `v1` or the like, there is no error.

The API docs do not state a syntax for release `tag_name`, but apparently there is. Anyone know where its documented?

Comment: TL;DR: GitHub uses `git tag` names for release names, and git tag names cannot contain colons.

Comment: Thank you @Dai. A replace ':', '' worked great.